# Fetch data in real time with flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have an issue in my app that fetches data by getting it from another website.  I want my screen to show the data in real time so if any changes happened on the website, it shows the changes in my app without the need to click on update or do any other action.

I tried to use future but I don't know how to use it. This is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FetchDataAPI {
  get(String url, String function, Map<String, String> header) async {
    List Response = List();
    Response.clear();

try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');

  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    // Internet connected
    try {
      var resBody = await http.get(
        url,
        headers: header,
      );

      print(resBody.statusCode);

      // 200
      if (resBody.statusCode == 200) {
        Response = [json.decode(resBody.body)];

        return  Response ;
      }
      // Not 200
      else {
        Response = [
          {
            "exception": false,
            "statusCode": resBody.statusCode,
            // Body here depend on response post man
            "body": json.decode(resBody.body),
            "message": null
          }
        ];

        return Response;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Response = [
        {
          "exception": true,
          "statusCode": null,
          "body": null,
          "message": e.toString()
        }
      ];

      return Response;
    }
  } else {
    // Internet not connected

    Response = [
      {
        "exception": true,
        "statusCode": null,
        "body": null,
        "message": "No internet conected."
      }
    ];

    return Response;
  }
} on SocketException catch (e) {
  Response = [
    {
      "exception": true,
      "statusCode": null,
      "body": null,
      "message": "No internet conected."
    }
  ];

  return Response;
}
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams), alongside [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)